# Modular application

Tags: web, asp.net-web-api, modularity

Recently we decided to refactor our old web ASP.NET MVC project. We decided to use modular architecture and build it around the ASP.NET WebAPI to write dependent and independent modules for it. Is there any tutorial or explanation or library helping build modular web applications?
If so, can you point me to this?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your necessity. If you need to provide service to the world outside your app domain go for SOA. If you need only project organization, just fallow **Microsoft Application Architecture**, or some **Business Architecture Guide for .NET**. You should see some of those guides using legacy `Web Services` or `WCF`, but `Web API` come to replace those in some way.

- [Service Oriented Architecture (SOA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb833022.aspx)
- [Microsoft Application Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650706.aspx)

Web API today already can go outside IIS, and It's easy to do that using OWIN middleware. This should be a good addition to your project given that you want modularity.

- [Getting Started with OWIN and Katana](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/getting-started-with-owin-and-katana)
- [Use OWIN to Self-Host ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api)