# Asp.Net Core Modular Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, modularity, modular-design

I am building asp.net core 2 modular application, I was having one module but now I am about to create another module and I get to the point that I need to develop a communication between the two modules, I need to use a model class from module A in module B, how can I achieve this without any dependencies between the modules
I do not want to put the model class in a shared project nor creating references between modules.

Comment: So, both your modules have different namespace, assembly name? or derived from common root namespace?

Comment: Each module has it's own assembly,namespace,models and services but all modules have reference to a core project and an abstraction project both have general repositories and dtos

Comment: Can you move your model class to core project having dtos? Ideally, model classes acts as dtos

Comment: That would solve the issue but is it a good practice, what if I deployed the application for some users without the module having this model?

Comment: If you move the model to core project then your module no longer contains model class definition. So, you will not require to include Module A or Module B for all deployment. Although, Core Project will always be needed in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules should not depend on another module, it can depend only on contracts. Some example. You have module `A`with intrerface `IModuleAService` and class that implements it, `ModuleAService`. Module `B` requires for his service `ModuleBSerice` implementation of `IModuleAService`. So create separate assemblies:

- `ModuleA.Abstractions`: containts `IModuleAService` and other contracts
- `ModuleA`: depends on `ModuleA.Abstraction`, contains class `ModuleAService` that implements `IModuleAService`
- `ModuleB`: depends on `ModuleA.Abstraction`.

And at your startup class you need register all modules. IoC will make all workds for you. If later you would like to seperate app into two, it will be easy. Case your need to 
implement proxy to access `ModuleA`.

Comment: Thank you, in your suggested architecture how can I get a list of a particular model for example Order which is in the models of the module A only?

Comment: Is it a good practice to have a shared project which contains all models required by any module?

Comment: Yes, it is. You separate abstraction and realisation. It's folows SOLID principles (class should depend on asbtraction, not realisation). In ModuleA.Abstraction declare service IOrdersService with method ICollection<Order> GetOrders(), in ModuleA implement this interface with desired techonlogies (EF, NHibernate, etc).

Comment: There is simillar question with some recommendations about modular architecture: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095572/modular-application?rq=1

Comment: Hello again,
suppose that I have a model in moduleA and that model require the another model from moduleB, you know in entity framework sometimes we need to put the an object from the foreign key model in another model, so the questions is 
where should I put the required model if I put it in ModuleB then I cannot see it from ModuleA if I put it in ModuleB.Abstraction then I think this will break the Modularity, correct?